# Updating GridView Data using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a GridView which needs to get updated on RowUpdating Event. How can I update data using LINQ?

I am populating GV using LINQ too and here is the code for that:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string getEntity = Request.QueryString["EntityID"];
         int getIntEntity = Int16.Parse(getEntity);
         using (OISLinq2SqlVs1DataContext dt = new OISLinq2SqlVs1DataContext())
         {
             var tr = from r in dt.Users
                      join s in dt.Entities on r.Entity_ID equals s.ID
                      where s.ID == getIntEntity
                      select new
                      {
                          s.Name,
                          r.FirstName,
                          r.LastName,
                          s.Email,
                          //r.Email,
                          r.UserID,
                          r.Pwd,
                          s.Company,
                          s.Description,
                          s.Phone,
                          s.Fax,
                          s.WebSite

                      };

             gvShowRegistration.DataSource = tr;
             gvShowRegistration.DataBind();
         }

    }
```

Comment: Guys:

I have 2 tables that I need to pull some columns from both of them. Now the problem I am having is using LDS is that, it is letting me choose only from one table. And my GV is binded to only 1 table. 

Now here is my next question:

How can I bind my LDS to multiple tables and show it to GridView?

Comment: You would not be able to use a LDS for this scenerio.  You'd have to do your databinding in code.  See the edit to my answer below.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I knew this was the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question or post comments to provide more information. Answers are reserved for solutions that actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do would be best accomplished with a [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx)

Here's a good tutorial on it from Scott Gu

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx

**EDIT**

If you absolutely cannot use a Linq DS, then in your RowUpdating event you're going to have to create a **new** data context, re-read the object based on the DataKey from the row you're updating, assign the new values based on your event args, and then save your changes.

It's going to be a pain.  Triple check that you can't use a LDS before going through all that.

Comment: The reason why I am not using LinqDataSource coz there is custom editing done in the page. I have to manually write my UPDATE Statement.

Comment: I am populating my GV using QueryString which is coming from the previous page. How can I bind my current GV then?

Comment: Oh - I'm pretty sure there are QueryStringParameters you can give the LDS

Comment: Pls see my latest answer! Thanks!