# why i can't edit anything in my DataGridView?

Tags: linq, datagridview, readonly

I got this problem. I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataSource` that is a Linq query, and when I show the data from my database in the `DataGridView`, I can't edit anything.

What's the problem?

Here's my code.

```
private void btMau_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var lst = from list in db.Maus
                  join dt in db.DiaTangs on list.IDDiaTang equals dt.IDDiaTang
            select new
            {
                list.IDMau,
                list.IDHoKhoan,
                list.Lop,
                list.BeDayMau,
                list.DoSauMau,
                dt.TenDiaTang,
                dt.MoTa
            };
        dgv.DataSource = lst;
        dgv.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip2;
        check = "Mau";
}
```

Sorry for my bad english!

PS: `dgv` is `DataGridView`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating GridView Data using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425407/updating-gridview-data-using-linq)

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to edit DataGridView populated with results of LINQ query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311683/unable-to-edit-datagridview-populated-with-results-of-linq-query)

Answer (score 0):

currently your variable is  read only. You can fix it by

```
var lst = (from list in db.Maus
              join dt in db.DiaTangs on list.IDDiaTang equals dt.IDDiaTang
        select new
        {
            list.IDMau,
            list.IDHoKhoan,
            list.Lop,
            list.BeDayMau,
            list.DoSauMau,
            dt.TenDiaTang,
            dt.MoTa
        }).ToList();
```

For more details and example, please [see this page](https://chikkanti.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/editupdatedelete-in-gridview-using-edm-with-linq/)